# Get User Data from Entry in View Page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, I was able to get the data from user through **Entry** and bind it in **ViewModel.cs**.

But, now I want to get this user data from Entry in **ViewPage**.

Below is code for Entry in .xml page and also of the Data Biding I was using ViewModel (it was working perfectly).

How could I get the user data through Entry in **PageView.xml.cs** too.

**PageView.xml**

```
<Entry
    Text="{Binding Email}"
    Keyboard="Email"
    ReturnType="Done"
    FontSize="15"
    Placeholder="Enter Email" >
</Entry>

<Entry
    Text="{Binding Password}"
    Keyboard="Numberic"
    ReturnType="Done"
    FontSize="15"
    IsPassword="true"
    MaxLenght="8"
    Placeholder="Enter Password" >
</Entry>

<Button
    x:Name="SubmitButton"
    Text="Submit" />
```

**PageView.xml.cs**

```
FormDataButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    if (Email != null && Password != null && Password.Lenght == 8)
    {
        // sample code
        var email = Email;
        var password = Password;
    }
    else{
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

**Data Binding I was using in ViewModel.cs**

```
private string _Email;
public string Email
{
    get => _Email;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Email, value);
}

private string _Password;
public string Password
{
    get => _Password;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Password, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean the code-behind, you just assign the control a name

```
<Entry x:Name="MyEntry"
    Text="{Binding Email}"
    Keyboard="Email"
    ReturnType="Done"
    FontSize="15"
    Placeholder="Enter Email" >
</Entry>
```

then in the code behind,

```
if (myEntry.Text == "blah") ...
```

however, if you are already using data binding, then you can just access the value via your VM

```
if (VM.Email == "blah") ...
```

Comment: wow, easy.. one thing, I want to check, if the length of Password is 8 or not, I used this `Password.SelectionLength == 8` but it's not working..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=netcore-3.1